# joomla Modules - Between Article or inside Article? What is correct?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I want to place articles and modules on my page. It should look like my scatch:

[image]

I am wondering if i can make 4 articles and one module (information box) and place this inbetween those articles, Or should i just create one article wich looks like the hole area (article 1-4 + INformation box)? So far i have tried to do {loadposition infobox-pos} into article 2. But than the box-width is not 100% but 50%.

Than aggain if i would make one big article with the contents from article 1-4 it would not fit great into my responsive layout.

I use T3-Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla doesn't support this natively, since module output is controlled by the template, and component output (in this case, com_content, view=category, layout=blog) is handled before modules are rendered.

You can proceed in many ways, I am listing them in order of decreasing ease:

1. Write a jquery script that moves the pieces in the browser.  You could also use mootools and it's bundled with joomla, but odds are you already have jquery loaded anyways.
2. Write a view override for abovementioned view: so copy /components/com_content/view/category/tmpl to /templates/your_template/html/com_content/category (copy all files).  Then edit blog.php and insert your module there, use something like /plugins/content/loadmodule/loadmodule.php :

   ```
       $document   = JFactory::getDocument();
       $renderer   = $document->loadRenderer('module');
       $modules    = JModuleHelper::getModules($position);
       $params     = array('style' => $style);

       foreach ($modules as $module) {
           echo $renderer->render($module, $params);
       }
   ```
3. Write a content plugin

Answer (score 0):

you can also use {loadmodule YourCustomModuleTitle} and place this in `<div>` with custom style attributes like
`<div style="width:100%;float:right">{loadmodule MyModule}</div>`
or
`<div class="something">{loadmodule MyModule}</div>`

Note: the module which loaded must be assigned to the same menu item or "all"